# Is there a way to get "classified" information from a company?

Tags: stocks

As a shareholder of a company (let's say AAPL) I would like to know what my rights as investor are. If I contact Investors Relations with a certain query (let's say their stance on a supposed leak of privacy related matters) they will probably just turn me down and deny statement. However I think this really compromises my stock position, so my question is: is there a way to get a better hint of the "truth"? Because right now I am only hearing one side of the "argument".

For context, I am currently curious about AAPLs stance on a supposed [tool that scans all the iPhones photos](https://threadreaderapp.com/thread/1423071186616000513.html). If this report would be true, I see a pretty huge impact on the companies reputation and therefore the sales of products and services.

Comment: FWIW Only the Government has classified information. Companies have confidential and proprietary information.

Answer (score 3):

Public companies produce annual (Form 10-K) and quarterly (Form 10-Q) financial statements which include discussions about the risks management believes to be material to the future performance of the company.  Any large company will also produce an annual report that presents much of the same information in the Form 10-Q but in a (generally) prettier package.  The company is under no obligation to provide you with a definitive answer to any random question you have or to officially take a position on any other question.  If the company views your concern as a material risk, they should discuss it in the quarterly and annual statements.

I am not sure what "leak of privacy related matters" you are referring to.  Conceivably, a company that was responsible for a breach of personally identifiable information (PII) would have obligations under various national and state laws to take particular actions.  For example, if unencrypted PII about California residents is obtained by an unauthorized party, [California requires the business to notify the affected customers](https://oag.ca.gov/privacy/databreach/reporting).  Other states and other countries have similar rules.

Although it is unlikely to be a practical option for you, shareholders do have the ability to [propose resolutions](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/shareholder-resolution-66531.html) that recommend particular actions to the board of directors.  If you believe that AAPL or some other company ought to take a particular position on a particular issue, you can submit a shareholder resolution and hope that other shareholders support it.  This generally isn't something that an small individual investor is going to undertake and it is very, very unlikely that the resolution would pass but it is an option you have.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the latter was probably what I was looking for, but I don't think that this will really be an option as a small individual investor. The 10k won't really help me as the topic I am trying to get at is probably classified and also I don't think they see it as a risk.

Comment: Is it possible to raise these issues during shareholder meetings?

Comment: @Flux - It is highly unlikely that a company like Apple would let a small, individual shareholder ask an unvetted question in a shareholder meeting.  There are generally way more analysts and reporters that would like to ask questions than there is time to cover in the meeting.  And if they did allow the question, the spokesperson would be under no obligation to give a direct answer.  They could (and presumably would) provide an answer that didn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Steve Jobs answered a journalism student as follows: "Please leave us alone." https://www.zdnet.com/article/steve-jobs-to-journalism-student-please-leave-us-alone/

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the leadership of the company is working on a key change of strategy which  shake the markets, but will also put the growth of the company on a rocket ship. They want to keep this under wraps for as long as possible, to allow them to beat their potential competitors.

Why would they risk that opportunity by telling somebody with an extremely small stake in the company?

But if you were a larger shareholder, telling you wouldn't help you very much. They would likely make you sign an NDA. That would stop you from telling anybody else. But you decide to double or triple your investment. That NDA would then become a prime piece of evidence against you if the SEC was to want to go after you for insider trading.